# jquery drop-down menu does not work on mouse click

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

We have a drop-down menu which includes autocomplete function. For example, if I write "Van", 5 closest matches are listed in the drop-down. However, if I select the last one with the mouse, the first item is selected. Here are the screenshots:

1) drop-down is triggered by entering "Van"

[image: drop-down is triggered by entering "Van"]

2) Even tough the 5th item is clicked, the first item is displayed in the text field

[image: Even tough the 5th item is clicked, the first item is displayed in the text field]

The version of Jquery Autocomplete is 1.1.3. I know this is an old version but the newer versions are incompatible with other technics we use.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can we see some code? A JSFiddle or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample app (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is not producing this issue (search for "Java" and select "JavaScript"), so you should review your code. The version is 1.10.3, maybe you should consider an upgrade, if that is an option.
Share the code you are using, so we can take a look...

Comment: We are now trying an update (v1.8.2 because it looks like to deal best with the incompatibalities). If it works, great! If it fails, I will give some code. Thank you very much